# The name "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy" does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1. After I create my API project, I run following commands

```
Add-Migration MOBAPP -Project OVMInfrastructure
Update-Database
```

When I run the `update-database`, I get this error:

> The name "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy" does not exist in the current context

I re-installed the following Nuget packages

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

but it's still not working.

[Click here to see my error picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyLgb.png)

Comment: Do you have multiple split projects in the same solution? You need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in the project which contains the `DbContext` defination. Share us your project strcuture and related code with `DbContext` configuration.

Comment: yes.I am using clean architecture. code with DbContext configuration are follows https://dotnetfiddle.net/nZhN4x

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` on **OVMInfrastructure.Data**? Is there any reproducable project?

Comment: yes . https://github.com/kajasumanie/UserCommonApi/   this is one part of my project.i just upload with one entity.If you can please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Steps below:

1. Install Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version 2.1.0 in `JSAInfrastructure`
2. Install Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` version 2.1.0 in `JSAInfrastructure`
3. Install Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version 2.1.0 in `JSAInfrastructure`
4. Update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to version 2.1.0 in `JSAAPI`
5. Build your project

[Result](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hhS5vTLGusJkZIDM)